# SQL Query Calculate Total

Tags: sql, math

So let's say I have data in my query like this:

```
Name: |  Cost:
Oliver     20
Oliver     3
Oliver     2
Sarah      100
Sarah      7
```

How would I go about merging the data for each person into one row and having a total cost?

Comment: Did you try google first?

Comment: of course. Want to be less passive aggressive?

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by and sum()

```
select name, sum(cost)
from your_table
group by  name
```